# If any value in list_1 is in df['1'], then return False, else return True

Tags: python

I  made a for loop to say "if **any** value in non_chain is in df['DBA'], then return False, else return True".  non_chain is a list of restaurant names and df['DBA'] is a column of restaurant names. This loop will let me know if the restaurant is a chain or not.

I would convert this newly created list "o" from the for loop, into a column in the df.

Problem: It is returning all False, and I am not sure why.

```
o = []
for x in df['DBA']:
    if any(n in x for n in non_chain):
        o.append(False)
    else:
        o.append(True)
print(o)
```

Comment: Have you looked at some tutorials on R syntax? This would be a good place to start.

Comment: Are you sure this is R code? It looks more like python. Make sure you tag the question correctly. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: omg, I meant to put the python tag. Apolgoies, I have been working in both languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you describe seems it should be solved with the simpler

```
o = [name not in non_chains for name in df["DBA"]]
```

`n in x` when both `n` and `x` are strings in Python means substring containment

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grepl`:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(X = c("A","C","G","G","X"))
non_chain <- c('X', 'C')

check_available <- function(i, lst){
    return(any(grepl(i, x = non_chain)))
}

df[, flag := lapply(X, function(x) check_available(x, non_chain))]
print(df)

   X  flag
1: A FALSE
2: C  TRUE
3: G FALSE
4: G FALSE
5: X  TRUE
```